# Vuforia - Display static objects in Unity without image targets

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

In Vuforia, you can use image targets to display static objects. You can also create a object in Unity's hierarchy which is displayed almost like a UI element. (refer to picture). [image: a]

However, I want to create an object that is static without using image targets, so the object is displayed immediately when the application starts. The user should be able to walk up to the static object and look at it.

Something I also noticed is that in the scene view, the camera does not move when the device moves. So if I walk somewhere with my device, the ar camera  should move in the scene as well. Is this possible?

Comment: Vuforia is image/object recognition. But it appears you want to do SLAM. 

Vuforia has the Fusion API which is a wrapper around ARKit and ARCore. Though it is still under development as of June 2018.

You should try ArCore and Arkit depending on your target platform.

Comment: If you aren't required to use Vuforia, you can checkout 8th Wall's XR Unity SDK.

https://8thwall.com/

It integrates ARKit and ARCore, and also has full 6DoF tracking on devices which do not support either of those libraries. Image targets are not required.